# Where is Heroku getting its RSA key from? It seems to be somewhere other than ~/.ssh/

Tags: git, heroku, ssh, rsa

I've had to create a new RSA key for pushing to Heroku. I've deleted the old key and added a new one to `~/.ssh/`.

However despite this, Heroku keeps giving me the following error:

```
!  Your key with fingerprint 83:3c:2c:45:81:5a:71:d7:40:2e:bf:fd:b7:e5:63:e2 is not authorized to access my_server.
```

I've been through each of the keys that exist in `~/.ssh` and have compared their fingerprints to the one that Heroku's complaining about. Only one of them had this fingerprint and that was the old key. So I deleted it.

Weirdly though even after deleting the key I still continue to get the same error message with the same fingerprint from Heroku. How is this happening? Is it pulling the key from somewhere else. I've tried even loading a new terminal window to refresh everything and it still makes no difference. I feel haunted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you remove both the public (mykey.pub) and private (mykey) parts of the key?

Additionally, your SSH keys are cached by the ssh-agent, though I don't think they would persist after removing the files. Run `ssh-add -l` to list the agent's keys, `ssh-add -D` to clean out all keys.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. You were right, it was being cached by the agent (even after I'd deleted both files). I cleared the cache and it's working again. Thank you!